# Simplest Private Message System [single table]

Tags: mysql

I want to create tinder/whatsapp - like message.

I have a table called "message" and I want to show all talk between users (last message)

Table structure:

```
message_id | user_id | recipient_id | message | status | date
```

Example rows:

```
1 | 1 | 2 | Hello | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:00:00
2 | 2 | 1 | Hi | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:05:00
3 | 1 | 3 | Are you there? I want meet you! :P | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:20:00
4 | 1 | 2 | How are you? | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:10:00
5 | 1 | 2 | Hello?? | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:15:00
6 | 5 | 1 | Hi :D | 0 | 2016-03-26 15:00:00
```

So, result should be (for user_id == 1):

```
3 | 1 | 3 | Are you there? I want meet you! :P | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:20:00
5 | 1 | 2 | Hello?? | 0 | 2016-03-26 12:15:00 ==> **This should show the last message between this 2 person**
6 | 5 | 1 | Hi :D | 0 | 2016-03-26 15:00:00
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT * from messages
where user_id=1 or recipient_id=1
ORDER BY date DESC
) m
GROUP BY user_id
```

But it only show last message from user_id not last message from both (user_id && recipient_id)

Comment: Why are you prioritizing a single table over a sensible database structure?

Answer (score 0):

which version of mysql 5.7 or 8 ?

```
select 
    m.* 
from 
    messages m 
join 
(
SELECT 
    max(date) as udate
    ,user_id as id
from 
    messages
where 
    user_id=1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    max(date) as udate
    ,recipient_id as id
from 
    messages
where 
    recipient_id=1
) t
on m.date = t.udate
and m.user_id = 1 and m.recipient_id = 1
```